# Sending Array through CMessage - OMNET++

Tags: c++, arrays, omnet++

I am trying to make a struct and send its data using the send() command to Application/MAC layers. Now issue I am facing is that send() only allows cMessage object/pointer as parameter. This is an issue which has kept the project stuck.

Things I have tried so far are:

- Inheriting from cMessage (but how to deal with array?)
- Overloading the HandleCommand functions but again send() doesn't allow sending an array.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `OMNeT++` one can define an own message. The definition may use embedded types (int, double, string, ...) as well as own types. 
Let's assume that you want to send an instance of `Foo` defined in `Foo.h`:

```
// Foo.h
#ifndef _FOO_H
#define _FOO_H
class Foo {
public:
    int x;
};

#endif
```

You should create a new file with `.msg` extension, for example `TestMsg.msg`:

```
// TestMsg.msg
cplusplus {{ 
#include "Foo.h"
}} 
class noncobject Foo; 

message TestMsg {
    Foo oneObject;
    Foo tab[10]; // example of fixed-size array
}
```

After building project, the new C++ files (`TestMsg_m.h`, and `TestMsg_m.cc`) will be created. These files contain definition of `TestMsg` class which inherits from `cMessage`. The `TestMsg` class has all needed set and get methods.

Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual, Chapter 6](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#cha:msg-def)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really works. I am having one issue though. If I intend to make a vector instead of array, it gives strange error. I know vector is allowed in OMNetPP, but how to include it here in message is a question which I have not been able to find answer yet.

Comment: There is no native support of vectors in message's definition in `OMNeT++`. But you can use `cplusplus` keyword and declare own type using `std::vector` for example: `cplusplus {{ 
#include <vector> 
typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
}}` And then in the message: `IntVector vec;`.

Comment: Thanks it works but I have made a class and using it in a message quite successfully. Whenever I try to use it in other message - a strange error of redifinition occurs. I have tried both noncobject and without it... What can be the reason?

Comment: I have omitted `#ifndef` directive in `Foo.h` in my original answer. Now my answer is updated, and `Foo.h` contains `#ifndef` - it prevents redefinition a class.

Comment: Apparently something changed in OMNet++ and this solution does no longer work. I get the error `Type declarations are not needed with imports, try invoking the message compiler in legacy (4.x) mode using the --msg4 option` on the line `class noncobject Foo;`. However without this line I still get `unknown type 'Foo'`. Any suggestions? I'm using OMNet++ 5.5. The OMNet++ documentation was not yet updated.

Comment: I suggest asking a new question, because updating this question may lead to misunderstanding.

Comment: Actually it seems that the `--msg6` option is still experimental and not the default yet, so maybe this is not that relevant yet. However the option is used in the Makefile of the `tictoc` example.
FWIW, after digging a bit deeper I found that (apart from changing to `--msg4`) replacing `class noncobject Foo;` with `class Foo { @existingClass; };` fixes the errors.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Recently there was a similar question here: [How can a standard container be added as a field to an OMNet++ message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786184/how-can-a-standard-container-be-added-as-a-field-to-an-omnet-message)

Answer (score 2):

This is the implementation that worked for me:

```
namespace inet;

struct NodeM
{
int type;
string description;
double coords[3];
};
// TODO generated message class
//
message Signal extends cMessage {
   NodeM Result[500];
   int sizeRes;
  NodeM RedQ[500];
  int sizeRed;
}
```