# How can a standard container be added as a field to an OMNet++ message?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I'm trying to create a simple [message definition](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:msg-def) that contains a field implemented using `std::vector`.
Per the [OMNet++ 5.5 manual ch. 6 sec. 8.1](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:msg-def:typedefs), this is seemingly straightforward.

However, I'm using OMNet++ 6.0pre6: I can't figure out what the correct way of doing this is, as the manual is out of date<sup>1</sup>, and the changes are very superficially referred to in the `nedxml` changelog.

The message definition can be boiled down to [the exact example in the manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:msg-def:typedefs), but in this case it is a `message` rather than a `packet` (either yields same error):

```cpp
cplusplus {{
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
}}

class noncobject IntVector;

message SimpleMsg {
    int this_thing;
    int that_thing;
    IntVector these_things;
}
```

The following errors were provided by `opp_msgtool`, the messages-to-C++ transpiler:

```
SimpleMsg.msg:6: Error: Type declarations are not needed with imports, try invoking the message compiler in legacy (4.x) mode using the --msg4 option
SimpleMsg.msg:11: Error: unknown type 'IntVector' for field 'these_things' in 'SimpleMsg'
```

Thinking *type declarations are not needed with imports* could be the simple summary of the changes from OMNet 5.x to 6.x, I proceeded to remove `class noncobject IntVector`. While it removes the first error, it still yields `Error: unknown type 'IntVector' for field 'these_things' in 'SimpleMsg'`.

Ideas? Suggestions? Lessons to be had?

**EDIT**: Notably found that [there are some notes in the `nedxml` changelog referring to changes between 4.0-5.x and 6.0](https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/blob/master/src/nedxml/ChangeLog#L77), but how to ideally use it is less clear.

---

<sup>1</sup> Certainly not wholly applicable to OMNet++ 6.0 at the very least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
cplusplus {{
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
}}

class IntVector {
    @existingClass;
}

message SimpleMsg {
    int this_thing;
    int that_thing;
    IntVector these_things;
}
```

An alternate 'solution' is to force the message compiler into 4.x compatible (old mode). Just add the following line in a makefrag file

```
MSGC:=$(MSGC) --msg4
```

However, sooner or later you should convert your code. If you want your code to compile with both OMNeT++ 5.5 and 6.0 then you should definitely specify the MSG compiler version explicitly. Either to be 4.x or 6.x compatible.

Comment: And yes, the documentation chapter in 6.0 pre6 is still not up to date. Try to look for examples in the INET Framework master branch. That is a big enough codebase and works fine with 6.0

Comment: Thank you! I found the `@existingClass` in INET4 messages and it seemed to work, but I wasn't sure if it was the ideal or correct way. That's very helpful -- again, thanks!

Comment: @Thor: "this" cannot be used as a variable name because it is C++ keyword.

Comment: @JerzyD. Thanks, I just re-wrote the variable names to something simpler as I edited the question and didn't think of it being reserved. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried second solution of the answer above, but new errors appear.

```
make[1]: *** [Makefile:282: veins/modules/messages/ReportMessage_m.h] Error 1
```

This is another solution, which won't get this error.

You could just change the makefrag files, by replacing all `msg6/MSG6` with `msg4/MSG4`. It will work.

Btw, the makefrag file's path is `...\omnetpp-5.6.2\samples\veins\src\makefrag`.